# Define copy constructor when keyword "this" is used inside constructor

Tags: c++, class, c++11, copy-constructor, ros

I am having difficulties while defining the copy constructor of my class `TextListener`. The class `TextListener` bind a method `callback` using `this` keyword. Please see the complete code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>

class TextListener {
 private:
  std::string _text;
  ros::Subscriber _subscriber;

 public:
  TextListener() {
    std::cout << "[" << this << "] deafult constructor called" << std::endl;
  }

  TextListener(const TextListener &other)
      : _subscriber(other._subscriber), _text(other._text) {
    std::cout << "[" << this << "] copy constructor called" << std::endl;
  }

  TextListener &operator=(const TextListener &other) {
    std::cout << "[" << this << "] copy assignment called" << std::endl;
    _subscriber = other._subscriber;
    _text = other._text;
    return *this;
  }

  TextListener(ros::NodeHandle &nh, const std::string &topicName) {
    std::cout << "[" << this << "] constructor called" << std::endl;
    _subscriber = nh.subscribe(topicName, 1, &TextListener::callback, this);
  }

  void callback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr &msg) { _text = msg->data; }

  std::string &getText() { return _text; }

  ~TextListener() {
    std::cout << "[" << this << "] destructor called" << std::endl;
  }
};
```

To test the above class, I created an instance of it, which works without any problem. However, when I create a new instance and assign this instance to the new instance, the new instance doesn't work. Below is the code snippet:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ros::init(argc, argv, "tet_listener");

  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  std::string topicName = "chatter";
  TextListener listener(nh, topicName);
  TextListener copyListener = listener;

  ros::Rate loop_rate(1);
  while (ros::ok()) {
    ROS_INFO("I heard: [%s]", copyListener.getText().c_str());
    ros::spinOnce();
    loop_rate.sleep();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The method `getText()` doesn't have any value. See below the output:

```
[0x7ffc5698a2b0] constructor called
[0x7ffc5698a2d0] copy constructor called
[ INFO] [1549031938.250136695]: I heard: []
[ INFO] [1549031939.250183378]: I heard: []
[ INFO] [1549031940.250170333]: I heard: []
[ INFO] [1549031941.250176834]: I heard: []
^C[0x7ffc5698a2d0] destructor called
[0x7ffc5698a2b0] destructor called
```

I guess that the copy constructor is missing something. **How to define copy constructor when keyword "this" is used inside constructor?**

Comment: Save the node handler and rebind the callback in the copy-constructor and -assignment functions?

Comment: I know what's missing: a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Probably `nh.subscribe` needs to be called again, or `ros::Subscriber` is not meant to be copied.

Comment: So presumably when you copy your Listener, the copy Listener gets a copy of the Subscriber, but that Subscriber has the same binding to "this" as evaluated when the first Subscriber is created, i.e. it's updating _text in the original Listener, not the copy Listener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two `Subscriber`s, one that notifies the original TextListener object, and one the that notifies the copy TextListener

You do actually have two Subscribers, but as the one in the copy TextListener is a copy of the one in the original, they both update the original TextListener's _text member.

I can't see a better way than keeping a reference to the NodeHandle in the TextListener, and having the copy constructor re-subscribe to the NodeHandle instead of copying the original object's subscription (which is calling the original object's callback).

Comment: Thank you very much. I followed your suggestion and it works like a charm!